Sale un cuadro blanco en el edittext en android studio
estoy incursionando en Android Studio, al momento de modificar datos (numericos) ingresados en el edittext, sale un cuadro emergente que tarda unos tres segundos en desaparecer, este cuadro blanco solo sale cuando voy a modificar cualquier dato en los edittext que ya tiene algun dato ingresado. Como puedo corregir esto?

